# What is the optimum way to return more than one data in a call function in PHP?

Tags: php

i have two function calls , caller calls for historicalxch function

```
private function historicalxch($arg){
   ...
     $data['MaxLow'] = max($data['ArrayLow']);
     $data['MinLow'] = min($data['ArrayLow']);
     $data['LastDate'] = $end->format("D, M d, Y");

   return array(json_encode($data_points, true),$data['MaxLow'],nth);
}
public function caller(){
    list($chart, $MaxLow,.,nth) = $this->historicalxch($arg);

    $data['chart']=$chart;
    $data['Open']=$AveOpen;
    echo json_encode($data);
    unset($data);
    exit();

}
```

i am wondering if how i could have infinite number of date return without manually setting list the number of return to the number of list.

Comment: return an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)!!

Comment: well it solely depends on the **data** itself...

Comment: @HirdeshVishwdewa is right! Since the `historicalxch()` method is "private" and the `$data` _seems_ to be a field; then, there is actually no need to return anything! simply set what you want to the `$data` member data, and use it anywhere, like in the `caller()` method :)

Comment: @someOne i hate you for that! the latter comment is just wrong, and create unreadable code where you can't know where and why members change their value. returning Associative Array Or either Sending Reference to member is better... even with the minor penalty of copying a pointer to the stack.

Comment: @TomerW I hate you to! Since you don't know that one of the most useful "utilites" for the "private" methods is to manipulate the member data of the class!

Comment: @someOne i hate me too :), i know it, it is not some utility, it is how objects work, they have members that can be accessed by the object methods, but still, creating a method that change some members and then using the members create an unreadable code where you need to master for long time in order to get familiar with "what affects what".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just return an array (which can contain any number of elements), and then in the calling function you can check the number of elements in the array and proceed as necessary. Obviously, you won't be able to use the list() syntax with this, since that would require that you know at time of programming how many dates are going to be returned.

```
function historicalxch ($arg) {
  //some code here creates an array of 10,000 dates
  return $array_of_dates;
}

function caller ($arg) {
  $array_of_dates = historicalxch($arg);
  $number_of_dates = count($array_of_dates);
  foreach($array_of_dates as $date) {
    //do something with each date
  }
}
```

You can also return associative arrays for more complex data. For instance:

```
function historicalxch ($arg) 
  return array(
    'json' => $json_data,
    'date_array' => $date_array,
    'error' => null
  );
}

function caller ($arg) {
  $data_structure = historicalxch($arg);
  if ($data_structure['error']) {
    die($data_structure['error']);
  }
  foreach($data_structure['date_array'] as $date) {
    //do something with each date
  }
  print($data_structure['json']);
}
```

If you want to write really reliable, reusable code, rather than an associative array, you would create a custom class that defines the data elements that you want for the return value. Then you specify that that function returns an instance of that class, and client functions can then use class methods to retrieve the data that they need. This is a lot of extra code overhead, but allows data types of the return value to be strictly enforced, so if you were to change the output of the function without updating the code that uses that output, it could be caught as an error with php-lint or your IDE instead of being a runtime error.

Comment: +1 for using a defined class for return data.
more readable than what i suggested in complex situations

Comment: thanks for the response this is very helpful even the explanations.

Comment: please rate up on my question

Answer (score 0):

Either return an Associative array: (or even just an array, if your caller know what to expect!)

```
private function historicalxch($args) {
    return array(
         nth=>$nth,
         data_points=>$dataPoints, ... );
}
```

or you can be more descriptive in what you expect, and intend to return using references in the function arguments (like in C/C++)

```
private function historicalxch($args, &$nth, &$dataPoints, &$MaxLow, &$MaxHigh) {
    $nth = 5454;
    $MaxLow = max($data['ArrayLow']);
    $MaxHigh = max($data['ArrayHigh']);
    ...
    ...
    return true; // indicate success.
}
function caller ($arg) {
    if(historicalxch($arg, $nth, $dataPoints, $maxLow, $maxHigh)){
         //use your returned $nth, $dataPoints, $maxLow, $maxHigh
    }
}
```